# Charles map local to HTTP query parameters instead of paths

Tags: charles-proxy

Does anyone know if it's possible to use separate map locals to query parameters of the same host and path.

E.g. I have the following paths:

`http://host/list/21?page_size=24`

`http://host/list/21?page=2?page_size=24`

`http://host/list/21?page=3?page_size=24`

Is it possible with Charles to map 3 map locals to those query parameters even though the paths are identical? At the moment, they just merge into one map local instead of 3 independent map locals.

Comment: did my answer worked for you? in case it does not: why?

Comment: I am not the owner of the questn, but your response didn't map a list different than the 21.

Answer (score 0):

The *Map Local* dialog offers you the possibility to filter by query, which seems to be exactly what you need:

[image: CharlesProxy map local with query params dialog]

You will simply need to add as many local maps as query params you want to treat appart. In your example, you should end up with something like this:

[image: CharlesProxy map local with querty params list]

(notice that I've replaced the second "?" from your URLs, I assumed you made a typo mistake)

This should work.